# Searching a set of keywords in Russian in Python

Tags: python, keyword, keyword-search

I am having a problem to import a set of keywords in Russian to a code I'm writing for the the extraction and calculation of those keywords in a corpus of historical texts that I'm working on.
My code looks like this:

```
f = open('keyword_rayoni.txt', 'r', 'utf-8')
allKeywords = f.read().lower().split("\n")
f.close()`

print(allKeywords)
```

I get a TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

I used the same code on an English set of keywords and it worked. I also tried to set the encoding for the Russian keywords to UTF-8, but it didn't solve the problem. Could you please help?

Comment: That code could not have produced that error.  Please show the complete traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `open` function wrong. Input `help(open)` in a python console. This will give documentation on the open function. If you read it you will see that the third argument is `buffering`, a different parameter which takes an `int` (but you are giving it a string, `utf-8`, see?)

Try:
`f = open('blah.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: They probably intend `"utf-8"` to be the `"encoding"` argument, and while it's *often* the default, it's still not a bad idea to explicitly specify it. Just use a keyword argument!